# Python test failed even after installing successfully

Tags: python, python-2.7

I installed  Python on windows 7. The installation process finished fine. I was trying to test Python by typing `python --version`, which did not work as shown in the figure. Did I miss any step?

[image]

Comment: Why are you tying the `python` command into the Python interpreter? You are **already** running the command.

Comment: The command line and the IDLE Python interpreter are **not the same thing**.

Answer (score 1):

You are already in the interactive python console!
Notice the '>>>' at the beginning of the line.

You are trying to read a variable called python. Which does not exist, because you did not define it yet. That is giving the error.

Open up a regular cmd.exe and type:
python --version

See if that helps.